# What to use instead of a USB to serial converter

Tags: arduino-uno

The usb to serial converter i found was $4 .maybe i could use something less expensive,like jus a port.I need serious help ,the serial port was about $1

Comment: To do what? You need to elaborate a bit more, this is to fussy!

Comment: To upload a sketch.....I don't want to use up cash without knowing what I'm doing.I've lost a lot of cash on experiments.

Comment: Any USB to Serial converter works. The only culprit is DTR, if that exist on the USB Serial, then you can program the arduino without any manual interventions, if it is missing, then you have to press the reset button before the Arduino IDE starts to upload the program, this will put your arduino in to "programming mode".

Comment: Here is a example on how a programming without DTR, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFARDFn8fs0

Comment: Oh by the way there isn't a cheaper way than a USB to serial converter. If you have a Arduino UNO laying around, you could use the USB to serial converter in that one, but you have to pull out the 328 chip first. Ref.: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard

Comment: You don't ***lost*** cash in experiments; you gain experience and knowledge, and have a wonderful time playing with things.

Comment: You can buy a CH340 adapter board with the standard "FTDI header" pinout (including DTR/CTS for auto-reset) on eBay for $1.46 with free shipping. You can get them as low as $0.67 on Aliexpress without DTR/CTS broken out.

Comment: "the serial port was about $1" What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest RS232 connection? It is an ancient tech but it might work for you. I am adding a [tutorial](http://www.arcelect.com/rs232.htm). Also a [component](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MAX232CSE-Transfer-Chip-RS232-To-TTL-Converter-Module-COM-Serial-Board-AD-/112071858489?epid=1586990854&hash=item1a1800d939:g:GrcAAOSwOtdYTeid) from eBay, which is 0.99 US dolar.

Answer (score 0):

> The usb to serial converter i found was $4 .

you can find old Nokia data cable (a form of usb/ttl converter) for less than a dollar, or free if you happen to have one.

alternaively, usbasp programmers are very simple / inexpensive.

diy is possible but you need to count your time. tools need to be reliable so i tend to rule that out.